# Java 7 Zip-JBinding Truncated zip file extracted from ISO

Tags: java, zip, extract, 7zip, iso

I am using below code [(link to full code)](http://sevenzipjbind.sourceforge.net/snippets/ExtractItemsSimple.java) to extract zip file which is inside iso file using [7-zip-JBinding](http://sevenzipjbind.sourceforge.net/).

```java
    for (ISimpleInArchiveItem item : simpleInArchive.getArchiveItems()) {
                    final int[] hash = new int[] { 0 };
                    if (!item.isFolder()) {
                        ExtractOperationResult result;
    
                        final long[] sizeArray = new long[1];
                        result = item.extractSlow(new ISequentialOutStream() {
                            public int write(byte[] data) throws SevenZipException {
                                hash[0] ^= Arrays.hashCode(data); // Consume data
                                sizeArray[0] += data.length;
                                return data.length; // Return amount of consumed data
                            }
                        });
    
                        if (result == ExtractOperationResult.OK) {
                            System.out.println(String.format("%9X | %10s | %s", 
                                    hash[0], sizeArray[0], item.getPath()));
                        } else {
                            System.err.println("Error extracting item: " + result);
                        }
                    }
                }
```

It works fine for some of the file [(e.g. this file which is 1.74 GB)](https://s3.amazonaws.com/rds.nsrl.nist.gov/RDS/current/RDS_android.iso), but when I try to use it with [this file which is 4.01 GB](https://s3.amazonaws.com/rds.nsrl.nist.gov/RDS/current/RDS_legacy.iso), it is getting truncated and extracted file is only of 8.26 MB zip file from ISO whereas actual ZIP file size is 4.00 GB.

How do I resolve this issue? Is there any configuration that is restricting this file to extract appropriately which I need to change?

Comment: Stepping through the code in a java debugger (netbneans) shows that a JNI native callback to setTotal(long) is receiving 8_668_223 for a file that the 7zip File Manager shows has size 4_303_635_519.   8_668_223 is  4_303_635_519 truncated from 64 to 32 bits.   So the problem might be on the C++ 'native' side of the library.

Comment: I have logged issued on their repo based on your comment. Let's see what they have to say about this. https://github.com/borisbrodski/sevenzipjbinding/issues/55